# Selling Digital good on Paypal

Tags: checkout, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal Express checkout into my website. Everything worked fine on the sandbox, but when I switched to live I keep getting the following error:

```
TIMESTAMP=2012-05-08T18:15:32Z
CORRELATIONID=e5550e81918f5
ACK=Failure
VERSION=72.0
BUILD=2860716
L_ERRORCODE0=10004
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0=You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Do I need special permissions to sell digital goods? I can't find any information related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sandbox gives you access to all of PayPal's products.  Some products, like selling digital goods, require a business account.

Here's PayPal's page on selling [digital goods](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/digital_goods):

> Sell more digital content and build more profitable customer relationships with [PayPal for Digital Goods](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/digital_goods).

Comment: Paypal API is so confusing... So basically you can't have an account that sells both digital and physical goods?

Comment: I believe you can have an account that sells both digital and physical goods.  You just have to have separate checkout processes.

Comment: For me it only lets me select either "Express Checkout" or "Express Checkout for Digital Goods". I can't select both. Anyway I only sell digital goods so it doesn't really matter.